# Using an enum to execute a function?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I want to call a function in viewDidLoad() in a view controller to set the behavior of that view controller's status bar. I want the status bar to have 3 behavioral states: regular, stay light, stay dark.

```
// view controller view did load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // status bar behavior
    // call some function
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

}
```

I don't have much experience with enums so please tell me how to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish. Ultimately, I just want to call one function in viewDidLoad() depending on the behavior of the status bar that I want for that view controller (regular, stay light, stay dark).

```
enum statusBarBehavior {

    case regular
    case stayLight
    case stayDark

    func statusBar() {

        switch self {

        // changes status bar depending on a variable
        case .regular:
            if nightTime == true {
                UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
            }

        // permanently keeps status bar light
        case .stayLight:
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

        // permanently keeps status bar dark
        case .stayDark:
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default

        }

    }

}
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the enum function `statusBar()` to simply return the status bar style:

```
enum StatusBarBehavior {
    case regular
    case stayLight
    case stayDark

    func statusBar() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        switch self {

        // changes status bar depending on a variable
        case .regular:
            if nightTime == true {
                return .lightContent
            } else {
                return .default
            }

        // permanently keeps status bar light
        case .stayLight:
            return .lightContent

        // permanently keeps status bar dark
        case .stayDark:
            return .default
        }
    }
}
```

Create a property to store the enum value you desire:

```
var statusBarBehavior = StatusBarBehavior.regular
```

Override the following property in your view controller:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
     return statusBarBehavior.statusBar()
}
```

Whenever the status bar behavior should change, set the `statusBarBehavior` value to `.regular`, `.stayLight`, or `.stayDark` and then call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearance()` update.

Also, if you have not done so, you'll need to set the `View controller-based status bar appearance` key in your `Info.plist` file to `YES`.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I've never had luck styling a status bar with overriding preferredStatusBarStyle. Instead, in viewDidLoad() I use UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent which works every time. Let me try and work your solution with that.